# Mysql : Get participants list of each conversation

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables `conversation` and `participants`, I would like to get the list of conversations and participants in each of them. Can I do that in only one query or I have to do 2 queries one for conversation and the second for getting participants for each conversation ?

I tried with

```
SELECT c.*, (SELECT p.user FROM participants p WHERE p.conversation_id =  c.id ) AS participants 
FROM `conversation` c
ORDER BY c.date DESC
```

But i get "error 1242 subquery returns more than 1 rows" and that's normal !

Comment: I think what you want is an `INNER JOIN` Can you provide the layout of your tables?

Comment: then use a join. you're using a subquery in a context where it can only EVER return a SINGLE ROW with a SINGLE VALUE.

Comment: It looks like participants has multiple entries for a conversation; in which case @ErikJohnson has a valid approach.

Comment: conversation : id, date and 
participant : id, conversation_id, user_id

Comment: Refer to any introductory book or tutorial on mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `INNER JOIN` to select parts of different tables where a common ID is shared. Like this:

```
SELECT c.*, p.user
FROM conversation AS c INNER JOIN participants AS p ON p.conversation_id = c.id
ORDER BY c.date DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now you are using a subquery

```
(SELECT p.user FROM participants p WHERE p.conversation_id =  c.id )
```

to receive a new column, in the table you are creating. A column only has one value for every row, not multiple values. So an error is thrown in this case. If you are confident that you will not miss data then you could force your subquery to return one each time it is run with aggregates

```
(SELECT max(p.user) FROM participants p WHERE p.conversation_id =  c.id )
```

But if the multiple values are different and still important, which in most cases is likely you want to do the join as mentioned by my friend Erik.

A join is likely what you are looking for.

```
SELECT c.*, p.user 

FROM conversation c
inner join
Participants p
  on p.conversation_id = c.id
ORDER BY c.date DESC
```